# Python Pandas Series.any() ==

Tags: pandas, any

Am I using pandas correctly? I am trying to loop through files and find if any value in a series matches

```
import pandas as pd

path = user/Desktop/New Folder
for file in path:
     df = pd.read_excel(file)
     if df[Series].any() == "string value"
          do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, check if this address your problem:

```
if df[df['your column']=="string value"].any()
    do_something()
```

I think you should fix also your file iteration, please check this: https://www.newbedev.com/python/howto/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory/